# CSS Fade Out HR Line issue

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to setup the fadeout css3 hr tag, it works on JSFiddle but I can't solve it on my site.

My CSS class on site:

```
.about-sidebar{
    margin: 25px 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(#1F1F1F), to(#FFD700), color-stop(50%, black));
}
```

HTML:

```
<hr class="about-sidebar" />
```

I have tried taking the class out of the HR tag and surrounding it with a div but doesn't solve.

Site: http://travisingram.net/ it is the "Welcome to my Blog" on the sidebar.

Jsfiddle working:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZTz7Q/1633/

Comment: What browser are you using? you have only provided support for webkit based browsers like google chrome.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was expecting, if you look at JoshC's answer you will see the other prefixes you need to add.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it wasn't working on your website was because the `<hr>` didn't contain the class with the gradient styling. Currently, you just have `<hr>` which should be changed to `<hr class="line">` or whatever class you're using.

Aside from that, the linear-gradients needs some tweaking and cross browser prefix vendors for more support.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/N55nr/)

I don't know what colors you want.. but here is black to transparent.

```
.line {
    margin: 25px 0;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.98) 2%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 90%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.98) 2%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 90%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.98) 2%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 90%);
}
```

Comment: For each line, is the rga left, middle, right? I was hoping to have it go from a Golden Yellow to Black.

Comment: Nothing I do will change the color on my site... Even if I match things just as the jfiddle link. Doesn't do anything . .

Comment: @Travis It works now. I noticed you changed it... http://i.stack.imgur.com/xr46E.png .. make sure you refresh the browser, maybe clear cache.. it appears to be a caching issue.. it works now.

Comment: So I finally got it to display, but whenever the slider causes the page to move up/down, the line seems to stretch and move in width.
http://travisingram.net/